# How to use the default php.ini file?

Tags: php, apache

I installed php 5.6.6 as an apache 2.4 module.

When loading a page with < ? phpinfo(); ?>, it said :
 
*Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows*
 
*Loaded Configuration File  (none)*

So, as the doc suggests, I edited httpd.conf to point php.ini configfile (in C:\php56).
I also added C:\php56 to PATH and PHPRC environnment variable.

As I don't have any php.ini file in this folder, I copied and renamed the "php.ini-production" one, and edited path to extensions.

When I display the page again, it stays blank ...
here is the "php --ini" command result :
 
*Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  C:\Windows
 
Loaded Configuration File:           C:\php56\php.ini
 
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
 
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)*

Which step am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the phpinfo function is disabled in your php.ini configuration (disable_functions option)?

If that is not the case try swapping to the development .ini file which by default reports more errors.

Comment: Hi, disable_functions is blank. I switched to the development one, problem is the same.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with your .ini file setup because I have the equivalent output from `php --ini`. I need the proper opening PHP tag however for it to work: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Tried that?